# Cannot Resolve Symbol error when using URL

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, try-catch, httpurlconnection

```
class background_thread extends AsyncTask<String ,String , Boolean > {

    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        String UR = "127.0.0.1/abc/index.php";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(UR);
        } catch(MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    }

}
```

When I use the above code, in the HttpURLConnection the url turns red and Android Studio is showing an error *can not resolve symbol url*. What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 17):

I encountered the same problem. Just do:

```
import java.net.URL;
```

Answer (score 6):

Put the line which is openning connection inside of `try` clause:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL(UR);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // Do something...

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    conn.disconnect();
}
```

It is because the valiable `url` is a local one which is valid only inside the `try` clause.

Or declair the `url` outside of the `try` clause:

```
URL url;
try {
    url = new URL(UR);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // Do something...

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    conn.disconnect();
}
```

---

With Java 7+, we can use the *AutoClosable* feature:

```
URL url;
try {
    url = new URL(UR);
} catch(MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try (HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection())

    // Do something...

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Which is better practice of these two approaches? Declaring a variable on its own like that or typecasting? At least should declaring the variable include an initialised value (`URL url = null`)?

Comment: @Michael I have no idea about which is better but I prefer the latter. Because now we can use Java 7/8 in Android programming, we can use *AutoClosable*. `HttpURLConnection` or `InputStream` is  *AutoClosable* while `URL` isn't. So we should separate try-catch clauses to use the *AutoClosable* feature of `HttpURLConnection` or `InputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need a asimple 'gradlew clean'

```
"Click" on "Build"->"Clean Project" and that will perform a gradle clean
```

Or:

```
"Tools" -> "Android" -> "Sync Project with Gradle Files"
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
```

solve the missing resolve symbol.

You must of course have this too:

```
import java.net.URL;
```

Comment: Other answers had already covered this. You are not adding or answering anything new.

Comment: Please read the question carefully. The error was  "can not resolve symbol url" didnt talked about MalformedURLException.